# API Secutiry in combination with AngularJs SPA

Tags: angularjs, api, security, authentication, azure-active-directory

I am now heading into what for me is uncharted territory...

What i want to do is Securing my API with Azure. And i want my Application to be able to "talk" to it.

So i have already secured my application with what Azure AD Authentication has given us... i followed this method below:

Guide:
[Securing AngularJS Single Page Apps with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/active-directory/active-directory-devquickstarts-angular)

Video:
[AngularJS Module for Microsoft Azure Active Directory Authentication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8EkW9NoQlU&t=454s)

And i have no idea how to get this to work with my API or how to secure it proparly in realation to the Angularjs SPA Azure AD Authentication.

So i am not after a complete Guide or something i really want to learn this.
The thing is i dont even know where to start pull on the tread so to speak.

anyone know of any good pointers or have a step-list over what i should look at and also maybe in wich order or something like that.

Anything would be much appreciated!

Thanks In Advance - John

----------------------Edit/Follow-Up------------------------

Ok so i have managed to secure my Api and connected both the client and the api to the same azure AD in the old portal.

Both the API and the Client are now ssl-enabled so they use the https protocol.

When i try to get the contacts list from the api through postman i get "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."

Wich feels as it does what it should.

But, when i try the GET function through the angularjs SPA client i get a Status Code 500.

```js
    $scope.fillTable = function () {
        $http.get('https://localhost:44338/api/Contacts').success(function (data) {
            var peopleList = data;
            $scope.contactList = peopleList;
        })
    }
```

And for some reason my Authorization key is not even in the header as it should be because of the adal.js, as mentioned in the documentation.

So i get my authentication key when i log in and also if i only put like "api/Contacts" in the get funsction. Without the rest of the address that is.

but not when i run the get function as it should be.

[image: Authentication with initial load - auth token existing]

[image: Auth after using get fucntion with full url - auth token non existing]

[image: Auth after using get function with half the url - auth token existing]

Does both the api and client have to be in same solution for this to work? Because i have already fixed CORS and also set oauth2AllowImplicitFLow to true in manifest and also deligated excess in azure ad.

I followed these guides in combination with the ones above:

[Protect a Web API using Bearer tokens from Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet#comments-container)

[Integrating Azure AD into an AngularJS single page app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp)

[Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: What are you using to authenticate, opendId connect?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, Azure AD is Microsoft's cloud based directory and identity management service. Usually, the user who attempts to request for the resources (APIs, etc...) protected by Azure AD is required to follow the OAuth 2.0 authentication grand flow to achieve an access token from Azure AD. And set the token in the HTTP request's `Authorization` header against the resource.

For general understanding how authentication and authorization work in Azure App Service, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview?toc=%2fazure%2fapp-service-web%2ftoc.json

Your scenario, uses Azure AD and the OAuth 2.0 implicit authorization grant to secure its web API back end. You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-authentication-scenarios?toc=%2fazure%2factive-directory%2fdevelop%2ftoc.json#single-page-application-spa for the whole working flow. And adal for js SDK implements the functionalities to help you to use Azure AD for handling authentication in your single page applications.

After these basic knowledge of Azure AD topic, I think you will have a further understanding about how Azure AD secures your back end web API, and how your client application authorize to your secured web API.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance! i will definitely look more closely at this. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so i have come a bit further in my quest for security so to speak. I would appreciate if you could read the edit to the first post above.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: As you got a 500 response which meant there was anything wrong in your  backend server api. If it is an authorization issue, it should be a 401/403 issue.

Comment: I'll take a look at it, but what could it be, is it that its not handling the token right or something like that? because i don't remember reading anything about any special handling except putting the Authorize attribute and also attribute for cors above the get method in the api. after all the setup and modification of course.

Comment: Ok so i fount what gave me the status code 500, it was one of the attributes i had over the get fucntion in the API. not i get a 401 non authorized and i guess that it is because my get request function in the client inst sending the Auth Bearer Token with the header.. and i dont know why it doesn't.

Comment: For troubleshooting, you can firstly set authorization header manually, `headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem("adal.idtoken")`

Comment: Ok, so what i have done is has been to check if i even got the token, and i did, confirmed after console.logging it. so the token is there... but when i try to manually add it to the header i get a 404 not found... i'm probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes, 404 means that the web server didn't find the route or the page. You may check the url, or the router on your backend server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130082/discussion-between-john-and-gary-liu-msft).